# What things should I focus on to find a frontend job abroad?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, resume, job-change

I'm currently working as a mid-level front-end developer. I have nearly 3 years of experience working in one of the top companies in our country. My goal is to find a job abroad in either Frontend or Fullstack. I'm open to both junior and mid-level positions, but more importantly, I want to fully relocate. I mainly consider Europe and Australia.

I'll highlight the following skills of mine:

- 3 years of experience with React. One multi-page personal project with this framework (from 2022). I worked with Redux, MobX, and I have some understanding of Webpack, since I had to configure its config several times.
- Firm grasp on algorithms. I solved around 2000 problems on LeetCode, and my rating wasn't too bad either.
- On the backend, I worked with Python Django and used to write some complex SQL queries. But honestly, I'd rather not take the backend route.
- I have a CS background, so I have some knowledge of advanced math and programming concepts.
- I have an IELTS certificate that proves that I have a C1 in English, so I wouldn't have any problem communicating in this language.

My questions are these:

1. Should I now work on improving my CV? If so, is it better to contribute to open source or work on a new impressive project? My GitHub hasn't been updated in almost a year, and I'm afraid it might throw a potential employer off. My goal is to get some interviews.
2. What topics should I brush on to pass the interviews themselves? Are there only "Data Structures and Algorithms" and JS-related questions? Or should I practice some system design as well?

[image: frontend resume]

Comment: "Abroad" is a huge place, so you might want to think well about why you would want to relocate to some country, why an employer would favor you above a local person, how well you will be able to understand business requirements and regulations etc. Your technical experience is most likely a minor point if you can't convince a prospective employer that you're a perfect match to their open position.

Comment: The first problem has to be getting to the new country. Many places can't hire you while you are in Russia. Once you are in a different country, then it is a matter of finding someone who will hire you to solve a problem.

Comment: Are you asking about relocation or "long-distance" work?

Comment: VTC - this is a question about a specific choice - and as others have pointed out, whilst not your fault - the War in Ukraine has made Russia and by extension, Russians Persona-non-grata for many.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I mostly considered positions in Europe with full relocation. I'm sorry, I should've clarified that in my question.

Comment: Change your current location on your resume. Get yourself a VPN, a Google Voice phone number (or equivalent), and a temporary mailing address abroad. Ask a friend if you can use their address, or hire yourself a private mailbox abroad that can open your mail as a service. If you can frame your situation as a Russian who has already left Russia, your resume is much less likely to be deleted right away.

Comment: I don't mainly find GitHub repositories filled with school projects to be impressive. You should focus on the practical implementation of the skills you learn to highlight what you did in the workplace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reality of the situation is that geopolitics means that it doesn't matter how good your CV or anything else is, you're going to find it *incredibly* hard to get a job outside Russia at the moment. If you do want to try this route, your first steps should be finding a set of countries which are less hostile to Russia and focusing on those rather than worrying about the details of your CV.

Comment: Thank you! Finding a less hostile country makes sense. I should probably do some research in that direction then. Still, it's a bid sad everyone is saying there's practically nothing that can be done to improve my chances.

Comment: Get out of Russia, cut ties to Russia, take a visible stance against Russia's unprovoked invasion. Or if you're feeling brave and want to make a significant difference in the world, stay in Russia and fight to fix or remove the current government; the whole point of the sanctions is to make clear to the Russian government that they are hurting themselves and their people (and hope they, or their financial backers, decide to cut their losses). Sorry you're trapped in the middle, but people are ultimately held responsible for the government they choose, even if the choice is just not to object.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it is sad, but it is reality. Very many programmers in Russia who had been hired by outside companies were told to either get out of Russia or be let go. That is why many left the country.

Comment: Imho, the hostility on the private side in many European countries (cannot speak for current day US) is pretty focussed on Russia as a state, not Russians per se (unless they vocally support the war). So many companies will have no problems hiring Russians, but the visa process can be more difficult - so that's where you should focus on, countries that will let you in somewhat easily (for you and/or the company wanting you to move in). The next filter would be language culture: some countries strongly focus on their native language, others have a more international culture.

Comment: @FrankHopkins thank you! That already sounds more hopeful. I understand that the visa process might require more time, but it doesn't matter as long as I'm sure I'll get it in the end. As for foreign languages, I also speak Spanish and Italian to some extent, and I'm a passionate language learner in general, so I don't think it'd pose a problem. I guess Spain might be one of the best choices for me then.